# HTML and CSS Based Gallery, Cannot make images clickable

Tags: html, css, styling

Im creating a HTML and CSS based Gallery. I want to make my images clickable in the page to become full screen. Will i need any plugins for this and if so where can I find them?

Comment: You should put you image tag into an anchor tag. Example: `<a href="#"> <img src="img.jpg" alt="my img" width="400" height="200"></a>`

Comment: <a class="expand" href="#"></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add jQuery for that. You can go to http://www.jqueryrain.com/ to view some plugins.
If you want your coursor to turn into the little hand while you hover on the image, use this

```
<a href="#"><img...></a>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the speedy reply, I shall I try this.